# Sidebar WP widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, sidebar

Ok, so this works and all is well. But I can't understand why it works:

In my functions.php i have:

```
register_sidebar( array(
 'name' => 'Welcome',
 'id' => 'Welcome',
 'before_widget' => '',
 'after_widget' => '',
 'before_title' => '<h1>',
 'after_title' => '</h1>',
) );
```

No weird stuff there. But in my loop file I have this, and I can't understand why it outputs a widget:

```
<div class="large-4 columns welcomeText sidebar">
  <?php if ( dynamic_sidebar('Welcome') ) : ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The if-statment says if there is a dynamic sidebar "Welcome" do nothing???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `dynamic_sidebar( $index )` to displays the registered sidebar.
What gets displayed is the content of that registered sidebar widget located at **DashBoard > Appearance > Widgets** and the function returns true on success and false on failure.

From [WordPress Codex:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)

> The return value should be used to determine whether to display a
>   static sidebar.   This ensures that your theme will look good even
>   when the Widgets plug-in is not active.

So your code should actually be

```
<?php if ( !dynamic_sidebar('Welcome') ) : ?>
```

Comment: Ok, see your point, I changed to !dynamic_sidebar.

But still, what is outputting the sidebar? No such code exists in my example.